# Do "mannish", "womanish", "girlish", "boyish" disapprove and "manly", "womanly" and "girly" approve?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

do nouns with "**ish**" tend to disapprove and nouns with "**ly**" tend to approve?

It seems like we don't often use "**mannish**" with men but with women to show disapproval.

***She looks mannish***

and we use "**womanish**" with men not with women to show disapproval.

***He looks womanish***

It seems we use "**manly**" with men and "**womanly**" with women to show approval

***He looks manly***

***She looks womanly***

I am not sure we apply it to "**girlish**" and "**girly**" and "**boyish**"

***He looks girlish***

***She looks girly***

***She looks boyish***

Comment: We're getting onto delicate ground here (gender politics), but, yes, to describe a woman as _mannish_ traditionally implies disapproval. _Boyish_ can describe either a youthful-looking man (usually complimentary) or a girl who wears her hair short and likes activities traditionally regarded as masculine (not necessarily uncomplimentary). _Girly_ is a modern coinage to describe an ultra-feminine manner.

Comment: "Girlish" and "girly" have different meanings. I can say "her girlish figure" where I wouldn't say "her girly figure", and "Her room was girly and done up in pink ruffles" but not "Her room was girlish.". "Girlish" is of or like a girl; "Girly" is characteristic of traditional femininity. Either of those terms can be disapproving, neutral or approving depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that -ish and -ly generally indicate approval or disapproval but there might be some bias when used by people who would like to enforce rigid gender stereotypes on others.

In informal usage. the -ish suffix means that something is slightly [whatever]. It can therefore used to criticise somebody who deviates slightly from the critic's fixed gender stereotype for their perceived gender: a man who has female characteristics is girlish, and a woman who has male characteristics is mannish.

The [-ly](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ly) prefix means "having qualities of, of the form or nature of" and suggests a rather more wholehearted adoption of [whatever]. When used about gender, it probably does suggest approval of somebody who wholeheartedly conforms to the critic's gender stereotype for their perceived gender.